# How can I find ._6182142_V1.csv in my folder?

Tags: python-3.x

I write this code in jupyther with python, to get the files in the folder

```
import os

path, dirs, files = next(os.walk("/Volumes/Samsung_T5/6182142"))

print(files)
```

and I get this result
[Files in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQJ5q.png)

But I don't understand why this file `"._6182142_V1.csv"` is displayed to me even though I can't see it in the folder.

[Real Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sceCE.png)

Can someone tell me how to view this file in the folder?

Thank you

Comment: The filename starts with a dot `.`, so it is usually hidden by you file manager. You must have an option somewhere to show hidden files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer.
Do you have any idea how I can display the file in macOS?

Comment: `ls -a`. `-a` flag is for "all".

Answer (score 0):

A file starting with ._ is likely hidden on your OS. If you view the hidden files, you should see it.